# Is TFS part of Visual Studio Ultimate 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have installed trial version of Visual Studio Ultimate 2012. Is TFS part of it or do I need to download TFS 2012 separately and then install?

Answer (score 1):

No TFS is not part of Visual Studio, you need to install it on a separate server, you can find additional information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server.

If you dont want to install TFS you can use TFS Online which is free if you have less then 5 users: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-online-user-plans-vs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

the TFS client is under the View menu and is called 'TeamExplorer', the TFS server itself is a separate install that would run on a different box. You'd connect to TFS via TeamExplorer